# Slow sftp for one user

Tags: ssh, sftp, filezilla

Remote user across the country has latency issues transferring files over SFTP using filezilla client to access our shared filesystem (CentOS 6 machines running OpenSSH).

One of twenty geographically nearer remote users (he lives one block down the street) has similar issues, consistently experiencing speeds between 5kbps and 60kbps when our tiny office is demonstrably capable of more and under low load at the time.

Traffic shaping does not appear to be an issue as it remains even when we encapsulate them in VPN to here.  They also have better performance from other sites.

Similarly, most of our users average around ~500kpbs down, and we have a dual wan with 10Mbps Upstream on each (load balancing might have been a factor, but I bound ssh protocol to one wan and saw no improvement).

Is the issue the client, the protocol, the server, or the ISP?

Here's the result of a pair of traceroute/tracert that I just ran:
https://gist.github.com/nonconvergent/637691e3d086b59172e9

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like an ISP issue to me with high latency.

Try running pingtest.net to see what type of latency you get to various servers.

Comment: It's not great. He gets a ping of about 100ms to us here with occasionally 400ms.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/nonconvergent/637691e3d086b59172e9